# All buttons effect only the first button, but not themselves

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, button

card.vue is the template with the toggleLike method and the button tag

```
<template>
  <div
    class="p-24 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-12"
  >
    <div
      v-for="movie in movies"
      :key="movie.imdbID"
    >
      <card :movieData="movie" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have dynamically generated buttons, but whichever I click, every time the first one gets "selected" or diselected (depends on its previous state).
I want to toggle them independently.

```
<button  @click="toggleLike()" class="mr-2">
        <i id="but" class="fa-thumbs-up" :class="{ fas: isLiked, far: !isLiked }"></i>
```

```
 toggleLike() {
      if(this.movieData.likes == 0) {
          $('#but').removeClass('far');
        $('#but').addClass('fas');
                this.movieData.likes+1;
        }
        else {
          $('#but').removeClass('fas');
        $('#but').addClass('far');}
      return this.$store.dispatch("updateMovieLikes", {
        imdbID: this.movie.imdbID,
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, You could actually shift-away from `jquery` with `vue`. You already made a dynamic class binding on your `but` element therefore you can remove the `jquery` class handling on your `method`.

*template:*

```
<button @click="toggleLike()" class="mr-2">
        <i class="fa-thumbs-up" :class="isLiked ? 'fas' : 'far'"></i>
</button>
```

*method:*

```
toggleLike() {
  // Add here how you handle the toggling of isLiked data
  
  if (this.movieData.likes === 0) this.movieData.likes++;
  
  return this.$store.dispatch("updateMovieLikes", {
    imdbID: this.movie.imdbID,
  });
},
```

*Note.*

I'm not sure how you generate the buttons dynamically, can you show it on your question? (can't comment yet). You should also show how do you handle the toggling of your `isLiked` data.

Comment: I need it in order to display whether the button is clicked or not

Comment: are you referring to jquery? You can handle that on your `toggleLike()` method. You can edit your question to show a more structured code, so we can guide you better.

Comment: I believe the buttons are generated with  v- for  loop , since they're part of the template called card.vue

Answer (score 0):

You should put more code on how you structure your generated buttons, is that an array? If it is then your isLiked should be an array

```
<div v-for="movie in movies">
  <button  @click="toggleLike(movie)" class="mr-2">
    <i id="but" class="fa-thumbs-up" :class="movie.likes === 0 ? 'fas' : 'far'"></i>
  </button>
</div>


methods: {
  toggleLike(movie) {
    movie.likes = movie.likes === 0 ? 1 : 0;

    this.$store.dispatch("updateMovieLikes", {
      imdbID: this.movie.imdbID,
    });
  }
}
```

Edit: Just a tip you dont need jquery in vue